# unabled to display some element and text at the right place in a card

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I develop a small angular material application. My objective is to obtain the following design for a card, that fit on every kind of media (desktop, mobile, tablette)

[image]

my "app.component.html" is the following

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <div style="width:100%;" class="md-toolbar-tools" >
    Liste des annonces
    <span flex></span>
  </div>
</mat-toolbar>
<div fxLayout="row">
  <div fxFlex="20%"></div>
  <div fxFlex="60%">
    <mat-card *ngFor="let annonce of annonces; let i = index" style="border:red">
        <mat-card-content style="border:blue">
            <img src="./../assets/image/image{{i+1}}.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:40%;height:100%">
            <div class="container" style="left: 45%; top:10px;">
              <div style="left:70%;">{{annonce.dateConstruction | date:'dd MMMM yyyy'}}</div>
              <div>
                <span>{{annonce.type}}</span>
                <span style="float:right">{{annonce.prix}}</span>
              </div>
              <h4>{{annonce.surface}}</h4>
              <h4>{{annonce.adresse}}</h4>
              <div style="left:45%;">
                <p>{{annonce.description}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex="20%"></div>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I am terrible in placing elements and text in html pages, and therefore in a material card. I obtain the following output in the browser

[image]

Furthermore when I shrink my browser, I can't see the element and text on the rigth of the image placed correctly. I tried to reproduce the same on stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pexq15?file=package.json), but I got trouble with the angular material tags that are not taken in account.

So could you help me and tell me what is going wrong and comment the correct code so I improve myself in html/css. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try leveraging the `@angular/flex-layout` Library for this. Additionally, you should consider moving your styles to your CSS File, since this will make your HTML File a lot cleaner and the styles more reusable. In your stackblitz you missed to include the styles for `@angular/material` in your SCSS File and you did not import the `@angular/flex-layout` module, which is why your stylings were messed up.

I tried to fix your example on [Stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pexq15) To get the desired spacings for your text, simply add paddings or margins to the left of those elements. Also beware of your image: You have to add a fitting height property, or it will become cropped/stretched.

Comment: Hi pascalpuetz and thank you for your answer. I followed your advice and now it is working. You can have a look on stackblitz